# Concatenating lists with recursion f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have an exercise that asks me to make a recursive function that uses @ to create a list of [1;2;3..n]. Unfortunately I cannot get this method to work.

```
let lstInt: int list = []

let rec oneToN (n:int) : int list =
    let addList = [n]
    match n with
        0 -> 
            lstInt
        |_ ->
            lstInt@addList
            oneToN (n-1)
```

I have tried making my list mutable, but that doesn't seem to actually matter nor make much sense as you can still add and remove elements from lists in f# even though it is not mutable.

I have also tried removing space between @ but that shouldn't matter either.

Edit: I should clarify, the issue is the lstInt@addList, which gives me the error:

"The result of this expression has type 'int list' and is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That warning is not the issue, but it points you to the issue: you're creating a new list which is a concatenation of an empty list and `[n]`, but then you're doing nothing with that new list. It's just dropped on the floor.

After that, you proceed to call `oneToN (n-1)` recursively and return its result. At the end of recursion, the very last call to `oneToN` will ultimately return an empty list, and that will be the return value of every previous iteration, since every iteration (except the last one) returns whatever the next iteration returns.

What you need to do is call `oneToN (n-1)`, which will give you a list of numbers from `1` to `n-1`, and then *append* `[n]` to that list. And the result of that appending would be your return value: after all, if you take a list of numbers from `1` to `n-1` and attach `n` to the end of it, you'll get a list of numbers from `1` to `n`.

```
let rec oneToN (n:int) : int list =
    let addList = [n]
    match n with
        0 -> 
            lstInt
        |_ ->
            (oneToN (n-1)) @ addList
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The recursive call needs to be concatenated with the list, that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: If my answer helped you, would you consider accepting it? You can do that by clicking the page grey checkmark on the left.

Comment: Of course! 

I have another small question for you though. Currently it makes a list of [5;4;3;2;1], if I wanted to get the list in the reverse order eg, [1;2;3;4;5], how would you go about doing that?

I know I can use List.rev after the fact on the entire function, but I can't seem to get List.rev incorporated into the function itself. Anyways, thanks in adavance for your patience.